# Issue with removing a git submodule

Tags: git

I have a question regarding removing git submodules. I'm organizing my config files and vim bundles using git, with the vim bundles as submodules. Now I'm trying to remove a submodule (per the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule/16162000#16162000), but I'm not succeeding.

```
--git submodule deinit -f vim/bundle/snipmate-snippets
Submodule work tree 'vim/bundle/snipmate-snippets' contains a .git directory
(use 'rm -rf' if you really want to remove it including all of its history)
```

So I try `rm -rf`...

```
--git rm -rf vim/bundle/snipmate-snippets
error: the following submodule (or one of its nested submodules)
uses a .git directory:
    vim/bundle/snipmate-snippets
(use 'rm -rf' if you really want to remove it including all of its history)
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong? Obviously just doing `rm -rf` like git is telling me to won't be good enough since the submodule entries in the .gitmodules file will stay. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't bundle able to remove them for you? (btw: maybe you should add some tags to the question, namingly "vim" and "vim-bundle" or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 'vim' and 'vim/bundle' are just normal directories, I'm using pure git. So `vim/bundle/snipmate-snippets` is just a normal directory into which the submodule is cloned. It could be anything else, `foo/bar/my_submodule`, or whatever.

Comment: Of course, but bundle does this for you. I'm pretty sure you can remove a plugin by removing the entry for the plugin in your vimrc and invoking something like 'Bundle clean' or so.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to `rm -rf` without the git:

```
rm -rf vim/bundle/snipmate-snippets
```

Then you can deinit the submodule:

```
git submodule deinit vim/bundle/snipmate-snippets
```

Answer (score 2):

You won't have this error message anymore with Git 2.12 (Q1 2017)

See [commit 55856a3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55856a35b20dae2499d4e0b23551c7ba9a33baf2) (27 Dec 2016), and [commit 83b7696](https://github.com/git/git/commit/83b7696605dbea3eb4e878cf904159f398345aa9), [commit 5a1c824](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a1c824f70ec261f8f9e5e039555fc80301dee0b), [commit bd26756](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bd26756112c0b9394f0aea0a77e7f713ffb0cd00) (20 Dec 2016) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3ccd681](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ccd681c2ab11522591be8a7a3eddb1a85a43ab0), 18 Jan 2017)</sup>

> ### `rm`: absorb a submodules git dir before deletion

> "`git rm`" used to refuse to remove a submodule when it has its own git repository embedded in its working tree.
> It learned to move the repository away to `$GIT_DIR/modules/` of the superproject instead, and allow the submodule to be deleted (as long as there
> will be no loss of local modifications, that is).
>
> When deleting a submodule, we need to keep the actual git directory around,
> such that we do not lose local changes in there and at a later checkout
> of the submodule we don't need to clone it again.
>
> Now that the functionality is available to absorb the git directory of a
> submodule, rewrite the checking in `git-rm` to not complain, but rather relocate the git directories inside the superproject.

This is what the new test "[rm of a populated nested submodule with a nested `.git` directory fails even when forced](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3ccd681c2ab11522591be8a7a3eddb1a85a43ab0/t/t3600-rm.sh#L661-L674)" now illustrates.

---

With Git 2.35 (Q1 2022), the error message *reall*y disappear: "[`git submodule deinit`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/670703e9d667f28221bfaa8baf75e90f0ba5ddca/Documentation/git-submodule.txt#L118)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-deinit-f%7C--force(--all%7C--ltpathgt82308203)))</sup> for a submodule whose `.git` metadata directory is embedded in its working tree refused to work, until the submodule gets converted to use the "absorbed" form where the metadata directory is stored in superproject, and a `gitfile` at the top-level of the working tree of the submodule points at it.

The command is taught to convert such submodules to the absorbed form as needed.

See [commit 0adc8ba](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0adc8ba6ae2b76501f4e0e57cc83d79be5305418) (19 Nov 2021) by [Mugdha Pattnaik (`mugdhapattnaik`)](https://github.com/mugdhapattnaik).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 670703e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/670703e9d667f28221bfaa8baf75e90f0ba5ddca), 10 Dec 2021)</sup>

> ### [`submodule`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0adc8ba6ae2b76501f4e0e57cc83d79be5305418): absorb git dir instead of dying on deinit
>
> <sup>Suggested-by: Atharva Raykar</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Mugdha Pattnaik</sup>

> Currently, running '[`git submodule deinit`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0adc8ba6ae2b76501f4e0e57cc83d79be5305418/Documentation/git-submodule.txt#L118)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-deinit-f%7C--force(--all%7C--ltpathgt82308203)))</sup> on repos where the submodule's '.git' is a directory, aborts with a message that is not exactly user friendly.
>
> Let's change this to instead warn the user that the `.git/` directory has been absorbed into the superproject.
> The rest of the `deinit` function can operate as it already does with new-style submodules.
>
> In one test, we used to require "`git submodule deinit`" to fail even with the `--force` option when the submodules `.git/` directory is not absorbed.
> Adjust it to expect the operation to pass.